# Can you get the next commit id before items are commited?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, hook, git-commit

I'm currently adding a commit-msg hook that will add the git commit URL as a comment to Jira.
The commit URL has the format

`http://[server]/[group]/[project]/commit/[commit_id]`

Is it possible to obtain the commit id or is it only produced after the item has been committed? Does this mean I need to implement this in a later hook?

Comment: You can in theory compute what the commit ID will be, as the process is deterministic. But one of the inputs is a time-stamp. Unless you force a particular time (you *can*), the commit hash is not predictable.

Comment: Why don't you put the id of the jira issue and use the addon that link commits in the issue: https://bigbrassband.com/link-to-commit-issues.html

Answer (score 3):

A git commit id is a SHA-1 hash of:

- The commit message
- Author and committer info
- The date
- The contents (the hash of the tree)
- The parent commit hash (or hashes, for merges)

So, the commit id can only be produced after the item has been committed.

Comment: Does this mean it will be produced before the push?

Comment: The commit hash is produced at the time the commit is made, which is before it can be pushed, yes.

Comment: I guess my only concern now is if I post the commit URL to Jira but nothing has been pushed yet, than the link would be a dead link... Do you know what people typically do in this case? It doesn't look like threre's a post-push hook.

Comment: @Sam You could do it in a `post-receive` hook. The hook works in the remote repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay I'm assuming the post-receive hook is located on the git server somewhere?

Comment: @Sam Yes if the remote repository is hosted on the git server.

Comment: @Sam: "Do you know what people typically do in this case?" I would imagine they either don't put the ID into JIRA until it's available, or they leave a note along with the ID that it's not yet pushed to the shared repo.